# How to do Data Bind with pivotgrid in Winforms using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, devexpress

I want to display records in pivot grid (devexpress). The data will return from **Stored Procedure**

`pivotTest` is the name of pivotgrid,I can give the connection String later. But I don't how to bind data to pivot grid.

One more doubt. In which scenario,we should use **SqlDataReader** and **SqlDataAdapter**

```
private void ReportTestForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cs = "";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spProcedureTest", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            pivotTest.DataSource = rd;
            pivotTest.DataBindings;
        }

    }
```

Comment: May be your tags are wrongs. Use `asp.net` and `winforms` both ?

Comment: @MIdrees thanks, Do you know answer for my question/